# How to add views to a UITableViewCell asynchronously in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

In my app, I have a UITableView with huge UITableViewCell's. Each of the cells are dynamic and created at the run time. By saying dynamic not just the content, but the layouts are dynamic as well. The problem is, it takes too long and it stutters when you scroll. Especially when a new cell is entering screen there is at least 1 second freeze.

Is there any way to improve this performance? I checked out this tutorial on loading cells asynchronously:

https://blog.uship.com/shippingcode/populating-uitableviewcells-asynchronously-to-fix-uitableview-lag/

However, this tutorial shows how to load datas asynchronously into static cells. I need to load dynamic data to dynamic layouts.

Comment: In which language, you want your solution ? objc c or swift ?

Comment: I am using swift. But any solution will do at this point. Im out of options.

Comment: Do you have image on  cell from server ? or just data ?

Comment: I have a lot of different things depending on the object. It could have images labels textfields, spreadsheet ables scrollviews barcharts etc... basically everything.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some few tips i hope that will help you

1>> Try to reuse your tableview cell by providing them the reusable identifier in your cell xib (If cell is custom ).

2>> Check for the loop in cellForTheRowAtIndexPath method (Do not perform looping in that).

3>> If you are downloading some data like images in cellForTheRowAtIndexPath method ,make sure you download it asynchronously.

4>> Perform the UI task like setting image in cell on the main thread like

```
[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:{
}];
```

5>> Ovoid over conditioning in cellForTheRowAtIndexPath method like many if and else statements.
[image]

Comment: I can't really reuse the cells since every one of them is different.

Comment: Set the image or data in your label on main thread in cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod.   

[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:{
}];

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have lots of condiitons in cellForRow method. Will recude them a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I have added a custom view on cell and a imageview on on that custom view. You can add UILabel, UIButton or anything.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString * CellIndentifier = @"CellIndentifier";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    }


 UIView *cellVW ;
 UIImageView *logoImg;

cellVW = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, tableView.frame.size.width-20, 216)];
cellVW.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellVW.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
cellVW.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cellVW.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
[cell addSubview:cellVW];

logoImg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
logoImg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width-20, 140);
logoImg.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
logoImg.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];




 NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {

     if(error == nil)
     {
         NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

         if([httpResponse statusCode] == 200)
         {
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

             logoImg.image = image;


         }
         else
         {

         }
     }
 }];



    [cellVW addSubview:logoImg];

    return cell;


 }
```

Comment: This assumes there is a UIImageView in cell to begin with. What I need is also creating the UIImageView async.

Comment: You have two steps here i shown. Creating the element in a thread, and setting their value locally or from server. This is the rules so far. Your main target should be avoid freezing UI. What's your objectives ?

Comment: See in your reference code : I have seen their animation. I did such kind of work many times. Note this lines:   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -&gt; Void in
 
        let text = self.model.textForIndexPath(indexPath)
 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -&gt; Void in
 
            cell.textLabel?.text = text
 
        })
    })

Comment: I have modified it another step. For creating uiview, uilabel, uibutton, UI won't hamper. UI actually hamper for Data.

Comment: I will try to implement something like this and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Just load 1000 cell and see what happens. Dont forget to fix cell height. Otherwise you wont see anything.